# How can I event.preventDefault() when using jQuery's mousedown and mouseup methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am using `event.preventDefault()` to prevent concatenation of `#` which is the href of an anchor to the URL.  I am performing events on the `mousedown()` and `mouseup()` parts of the click which is why I can't use click.  But `event.preventDefault()` is not preventing the concatenation of `#` to the URL when envoking `mouseup()` or `mousedown()` methods.  How can I get around this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're talking about clicking a link, it is probably because there isn't a default behavior to prevent for `mousedown` and `mouseup`.

The default behavior of clicking a link requires a combination of `mousedown` plus `mouseup` on the link. If you `mousedown` then drag off the link before you `mouseup`, the link is not followed. The same vice-versa.

Only when you `mousedown` then `mouseup` is the default behavior activated. That event is represented by the `click` event.

---

**EDIT:** *I guess I forgot to answer the question.*

How do you get around it? Add a `click()` event handler that does `e.preventDefault()`.

```
$('a.myElement').click(function(e){e.preventDefault()});
```

If you also want to stop propagation of the event, and if you're using jQuery 1.4.3 or later, you can do this:

```
$('a.myElement').bind('click',false);
```

**From the docs for the [`bind()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) method:**

> Setting the third argument to false will attach a function that prevents the default action from occurring and stops the event from bubbling.

Again, it requires `jQuery 1.4.3` or later.